# Is there a way to display half loaded html or php

Tags: php, html, sleep, browser-refresh

I have a html page that runs several consecutive php/bash scripts, and I would like to make the result visible on the page, before the next script starts. Is that possible?

Example:

```
<html> <body>
<br>Html1<br>
<?php
echo "A";
sleep(4);
echo "B";
?>
<br>Html2<br>
<?php
echo "C";
sleep(4);
echo "D";
?>
<br>Html3<br>
</body> </html>
```

...here nothing is shown before everything is done.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a buffering issue.

Do `flush()` between consecutive `echo`s to flush the PHP's internal output buffers.

Note though that your webserver may do additional buffering and so can the browser, so it is not really guaranteed that the changes will be displayed in browser.

If you want to test if other buffering is involved, you can post a long HTML comment after each output.

For example:

```
<?php
  echo "<!-- aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ... aaa -->";
?>
```

If the comment is long enough it will fill the buffer, forcing it to flush.

**Please note that this is ONLY for testing, do NOT use that in production code.**

Comment: That won't do it. (It doesn't show up even when output buffering is disabled.) Did you mean: [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush)?

Comment: @minitech it should be enabled

Comment: Well PHP buffers internaly even without using `ob_` functions

Comment: You are right, I meant `flush()` but from my experience `ob_flush()` implicitly calls the `flush()`, so it's kinda the same.

Comment: No it is not working :o( - tried to add `flush()` to the example, but it made no difference.